# Using OpenFileDialog and StreamReader

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, streamreader, openfiledialog

There are two classes, one to cover the form (class 1) and the other to cover what gets displayed on the form (class 2).  I'm trying to call a method in class 1 from class 2 to display certain information in a text box.  I keep getting the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

I've encountered this error before and been able to make it through, but nothing I've attempted so far has helped in this instance.  I'm posting code for both the classes.

Class 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project6
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;

        //Create an instance of the open file dialog box
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        //Set parameters, filter options, and filter index
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        ofd.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt";
        ofd.FilterIndex = 2;

        ofd.Multiselect = false;

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = ofd.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream = ofd.OpenFile())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream);

                        string studentInformation = "";
                        string[] studentInformationArray = new string[11];
                        studentInformation = reader.ReadLine();

                        while ((studentInformation = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            studentInformationArray = studentInformation.Split(',');
                            Student newStudent = new Student(studentInformationArray);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.  Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Student.GetName(); //This generates the compiler error
        textBox1.Select(6, 5);
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.SelectedText);
    }
}
}
```

Class 2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project6
{
class Student
{
    //Initialize variables
    private string[] studentInformationArray;

    //Constructor that accepts the studentInformationArray as an argument
    public Student(string[] studentInformationArray)
    {
        this.studentInformationArray = studentInformationArray;
    }

    public Student()
    {
        string className = studentInformationArray[1];
        string semester = studentInformationArray[2];
        string picture = studentInformationArray[3];
        int project1 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[4]);
        int project2 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[5]);
        int project3 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[6]);
        int project4 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[7]);
        int project5 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[8]);
        int project6 = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[9]);
        int midtermExam = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[10]);
        int finalExam = Convert.ToInt32(studentInformationArray[11]);
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        string studentName;
        studentName = studentInformationArray[0];
        return studentName;
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the documentation of [OpenFileDialog on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

is what I was looking at, but apparently that's wrong.

Comment: Thats for a different platform - notice the **Silverlight** at the top?  If you hit F1 in your code over a NET keyword/object/type it will take you to the correct page (usually)

Comment: I see that now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that's not how you use the OpenFileDialog. Take a look at this example hosted by the MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

Edit: answering to your edited question. You will always get a NullReferenceException in the Student() constructor because you are never assigning something to your studentInformationArray. So you can fix it like this:

```
public Student()
{
    studentInformationArray = new studentInformationArray[12];
    string className = studentInformationArray[1];
    // rest of your code...
}
```

However, you should take into account that studentInformationArray will be an empty array unless you assign something to it. Since you have a Student() overload that takes a string[], I'd suggest you that you either remove the default constructor or make it call the overloaded with default information, like this:

```
public Student(string[] studentInformationArray)
{
     string className = studentInformationArray[1];
     // rest of your code...
     int project1 = int.Parse(studentInformationArray[4]); // always prefer int.Parse() instead of Convert.ToInt32()
     // rest of your code...
     this.studentInformationArray = studentInformationArray;
}

public Student()
{
    string[] defaultInformation = new string[12];
    // add information
    defaultInformation[0] = "some information";
    // ...
    new Student(defaultInformation);
}
```

Some more points to take into account:

- Class-level fields/properties should be spelled in Pascal Case (first letter of each word in uppercase, rest in lowercase)
- Try to never use this.variableName = variableName.
- Variables names should never include the type of the variable, that's redundant.

So, for example, change this:

```
private string[] studentInformationArray;
```

for this:

```
private string[] StudentInformation;
```

Answering your last question, regarding the compiler error, you need a reference to the Student read in order to get its name. You could do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Student StudentRead;
    // rest of your code...
    // from your read method:
    StudentRead = new Student(studentInformationArray); 

    // and finally:
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = StudentRead.GetName();
```

Comment: Thank you for the nudge in the right direction.  I fixed the initial problem, but I have encountered another that I can't seem to get past (and I know it's probably an easy fix).  Would you mind looking at the edited code I posted?  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I'm completely lost.  I don't understand why the array isn't being populated when the file is read and then the array sent as an object to the Student class.  Once the array is in the Student class, shouldn't I just be able to access all the elements?  So, for example:

public string GetName()
{
   string studentName;
   studentName = studentInformationArray[0];
   return studentName;
}

Aren't I assigning the value of what's in that spot of the array to studentName?  If so, then why can't I just call GetName from the other class?

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate your help.  The user is suppose to be able to select a text file that contains certain information.  When the file is read by the program it's suppose to split the text file into separate components based on a " , ".  The separate components are suppose to populate an array.  I need to use the information within the array and perform operations on the array to populate textboxes/labels on the form.  I hope that gives a little more insight.

Comment: @MatthewSpire what you are missing is a way to store in-memory all the students you read from the file. Take a look at List<T> while I implement something very basic for you

Comment: There's only one student in the text file and only one text file should be allowed to be opened at one time.  Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97142/discussion-between-cfrozendeath-and-matthewspire).